# Undefined error when using data attribute with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, undefined

I'm using jquery to build a like and dislike on comments system, so I need jquery manipulation.
To achieve this I'm using data attribute, but I get a undefined error with this code

I've been trying this for hours and I cant get it to alert the value of data attribute.

My javascript code:

```
$('.unlike_link_comment').live("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var likescount = jQuery(this).attr("data-likes");
    var newlikescount = parseInt(likescount) - 1;
    var commentid = jQuery(this).attr("data-id");
    var dislikescount = jQuery('#dislike_link_comment_4').data("dislikes");
    alert(dislikescount);
    $.ajax({
    url : 'alter_comments.php?action=unlike&comment_id='+commentid,
    beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
    xhr.overrideMimeType( 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8' );
  },
    success: function( data ) {
    $('#emptydiv_'+commentid).html(data);
    $('#like_count_'+commentid).html('<font color="red">'+newlikescount+' Likes</font>');
    $('#comment_control_'+commentid).html("<a data-likes='"+newlikescount+"' data-id='"+commentid+"' href='' class='like_link_comment'>Like</a> ");  
  }
    });    
    });
```

My HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class='stbody' id='stbody_4'>
<div class='stimg'>
<img src='uploads/profile_pics_small/wood_texture_by_pabloalvin-d1igijr.jpg' /></img>
</div>
<div class="unlike_link_comment" style="width: 100px; height: 50px; margin: 0 auto; background-color:yellow">click me!</div>
<div class='sttext'><font color='black'>
sdasdasd
<div class='sttime'>By nicknick</div></font>
<br><br><font color='red'><p id='like_count_4' class='like_count'>0 Likes</p> <p id='dislike_count_4' class='dislike_count'>2 Dislikes</font></p> <div id='comment_control_4' class='commentcontrols'> <a data-likes='0' data-id='4' class='like_link_comment' id='like_link_comment_4' href=''>Like</a><a data-dislikes='2' data-id='4' class='dislike_link_comment' id='dislike_link_comment_4' href=''>Dislike</a></div> </div> </div>  <div id='emptydiv_4'> </div> </body> </html>
```

Comment: Post relevant code **here**. we can't depend on external resources.

Comment: Don't use `.attr()` to access "data-" attributes.  Use `.data()` instead, and just leave off the "data-" part of the attribute name. Thus instead of `.attr("data-foo")` you just write `.data("foo")`.

Comment: @Marshall Mathews Hold on. Im downloading WinRar. ( why do you post large code ?) put a small sample

Comment: Also, don't write `jQuery` - you have the `$` shortcut available and use it at some places anyway. If you want to make your code work even with noConflict, simply wrap it in `(function($) { ... })(jQuery);`

Comment: sorry im just such a messy coder T_T
@Pointy, yes i've tried that and failed. But i guess i will give it one more shot

Comment: ok i tried it once more, im completely lost now. Please help me out.

Comment: Make an effort to make a simple and understandable question if you want a good response. Also, i threw your HTML in the http://validator.w3.org and it points out 12(!) errors - maybe start with that

Answer (score 0):

I myself am not very good at javascript, but when i ran it through a lint(javascriptlint.com), it gave the following error:

```
$('.unlike_link_comment').live("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var likescount = jQuery(this).attr("data-likes");
    var newlikescount = parseInt(likescount) - 1;
```

===========================================^
    lint warning: parseInt missing radix parameter

maybe that's the problem?